# how to redirect non existed URL to new URL through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

At my website one page is no more existed but its URL is being used in some other websites, so can i redirect that old URL to my newly created URL.

I have tried the bellow rule but did not work
redirect 301 https://example.com/old.php https://example.com/new-page

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldsite.php https://example.com/new-page
```

Comment: are your sure, that the .htaccess is set up correctly? what exactly is the error/problem/result

Answer (score 0):

some  guide for you [htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ store [L]
```